# NetworkCallback's onUnavailable() method isn't called if no Wi-Fi AP are found

Tags: android, wifi

I am trying to connect my smartphone to an AP made by an IOT device. I'm using connectivitymanager.requestNetwork() with a NetworkCallback and all works fine until I keep turned off my AP and obviuosly requestNetwork() doesn't find any network. At that point when I press Cancel I expected that onUnavailable() is called but instead the app remains at a blank screen. 
Here's my code:

---

```
  connectivityManager?.requestNetwork(networkRequest, object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()
         {
                override fun onAvailable(network: Network)
                {
                    connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
                    var intent= Intent(this@WifiDiCEActivity, ConnectDiCEActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }

             override fun onUnavailable()
             {
                 super.onUnavailable()
                 var intent= Intent(this@WifiDiCEActivity, AddDiCEStep3Activity::class.java)
                 startActivity(intent)
                 finish()
             }


             override fun onLost(network: Network)
             {
                 super.onLost(network)
                 var intent= Intent(this@WifiDiCEActivity, AddDiCEStep3Activity::class.java)
                 startActivity(intent)
                 finish()
             }

         }
```

---

What can I implement to get back to the previous activity if the phone doesn't find the AP? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this problem on Google Issue, and after some time they have marked this bug as fixed. It will become available in a future release.

Comment: Here is a link to the issue for those curious https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144891976

Comment: This could not be answer.. you can mark it as comment of question. for more details you can check Q& A  section.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue and need this callback method to ensure that connection is available in `onResume()` method.

The only solution I have is to call `wifiManager.isWifiEnabled`.